# Modified a non-owned file's properties on windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10

I have a certain software that gets detected by another, which causes it to stop running. From doing some research, I learned it was checking for the file in the task manager, and, if present, shutting down. I want to use both softwares at the same time. I tried to modify the first file's properties, with "Right Click >> Properties >> Details >> Remove properties and personal information" since changing this would allow both softwares to work together, but it seems like I can't modify them. I tried taking ownership of the file, which didn't change anything. Is there any way to do this ?

Comment: Hmm, are you sure that'll actually remove the same properties that the program is testing for?

Comment: Afaik, it's testing for the name in task manager, which, I guess, is the File Description.

Comment: Ah, well, that's _not_ something the button can possibly remove.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of those properties are actually in the EXE, which the Properties window will not modify. It is possible to tweak them, though, using a hex editor. I like [XVI32](http://www.chmaas.handshake.de/delphi/freeware/xvi32/xvi32.htm). Before you open the EXE, note the current value of the property you want to change and, if necessary, adjust the file's security settings to give yourself write access. You should probably also make a backup of it in case of accidents in the hex editor.

Once you have XVI32 extracted and running, open the target EXE. Hexadecimal is shown in the middle/left pane; the right pane shows the ASCII representations of those bytes. Press Ctrl+F to open the Find window. Make sure "text string" is selected and that "as Unicode Latin" is checked. Type `FileDescription` in the top box.

[image: the Find dialog]

Press the OK button. XVI32 brings you to a region of the EXE that stores several of the properties shown in the Properties window. Look up and down a bit until you find the text you need to tweak. (The name of the program as shown in Task Manager is the file description, which is why I suggested that search term.) In the right pane, click to select the text you want to change. If the status bar does not say Overwrite, press the Insert key so that it does. In this screenshot, I'm ready to start overwriting the file description of `IPFactorial`:

[image: ready to overwrite]

Type a character on your keyboard to overwrite the selected character. If you want to overwrite multiple characters, use your mouse to select the next one - do not overwrite the blank spaces (null bytes) with actual spaces. Do not try to change the length of the property value by inserting or deleting bytes. When finished, save and close XVI32. When you open the Properties window of the modified EXE, it should reflect your changes.

Comment: That did it, thanks a lot :) I was sure you could modify it with the basic windows properties editor, but I guess hexadecimal was needed.